# Edit Text Files using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, text

i want to edit text files using this nuget **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text"** (delete/replace text on **1 line or multiple lines** from specific start/end points & lines).
Can anyone please guid to how to do that?

Comment: Why? Besides, what do you think that package uses? Or is the *real* question how to modify the text displayed in a Visual Studio editor from a VS extension?

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you about the responses ,
i thought that i can take adventage of that package to edit text in files dynamiccly exactelly the same thing like we can do manually/visually on VS.
For exemple  : dynamiclly select a zone in file by its Position :StartLine,EndLine,StartColumn,EndColumn,then delete it,or replace it with other text,..)